# setOnLoadCallback does not work in loop

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am working with google charts and experiencing some misunderstanding stuff.

So to be short, I have many charts to draw, and instead of listing them, I would like to make a loop. But when I am converting the "call list" into a for..in loop, only the last element in the array seems to "work".

There, you can see an object called "allData" which contains many data and the function to call when "OnLoad" is triggered.

```
for (var value in allData) {
   google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function() { (allData[value]['function'])(allData[value]) });
};

//google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function() { (allData['ActionsBar']['function'])(allData['ActionsBar']) });
// google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function() { (allData['OtherBar']['function'])(allData['OtherBar']) });
// google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function() { (allData['ThirdBar']['function'])(allData['ThirdBar']) });
```

If I uncomment the last 3 lines, everything works fine.
I read that it seems to have known troubles with google charts and loops but could not find exactly that case. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

`setOnLoadCallback` should only be called *once* per page load

the purpose is to let you know `google` has finished loading, *along with the dom*

it takes a *reference* to a function

`google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);`

not the result of a function

`google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart());`

---

however, recommend *not using* `setOnLoadCallback` anyway

place the `callback` in the `load` *instead*

load google first, then don't worry about it anymore...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

Comment: oooh I think I got it. I got an idea. Gonna try it and I'll show you. I am pretty confident it s going to work.

Comment: Ok it works. Juste changer this:
`for (var value in allData) {
   google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function() { (allData[value]['function'])(allData[value]) });
};`
by
` google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
        for (var value in allData) {
           (allData[value]['function'])(allData[value]);
        };
      });`

and it 's all good !

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out. As I have been told,

```
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback
```

should only be called once, so I changed

```
for (var value in allData) {
   google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function() { (allData[value]['function'])(allData[value]) });
};
```

by

```
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
        for (var value in allData) {
           (allData[value]['function'])(allData[value]);
        };
      });
```

All good now ;)

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to call setOnLoadCallBack just one time

```
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(myCallBackFunction());
myCallBackFunction = function(){
    for (var value in values) {
        var data = //use value or what you want
        var options = //use value or what you want
        var chart = new google.visualization. //etc etc
        chart.draw(data,options)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I do not think so. What you told me to do is done by the lambda function there:

`function() { (allData[value]['function'])(allData[value]) }`

(Plus your code is wrong as you "call" the myCallBackFunction where you should just pass it as parameter).

Or maybe I did not get what you meant.

Comment: Only the last loop works because each time you call .setOnLoadCallback it erase the previous one

Comment: Are you sure ? Why the it does not erase the previous one when I make successive calls then ? And is there a way to fix it, you think ?

Comment: No i am not sure :) i edit the answer to show you how i was doing, it was working fine for me like that